# INI file doesn't work. It has an extra '・' at the very beggining. Why?

Tags: python, windows, encoding, ini, decoding

[image]

This is a part of an ini file someone wrote.
It looks perfect, but python won't read it properly.

I read it via Python and happened to find '・' at the very first line, which shouldn't be here.
Like below.
[image]

Could you explain to me why this happens?
Running environment is Windows but I have no clue about what environment a guy wrote this ini in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should comes from the encoding and decoding. When users try editing the ini file from windows Notepad, especially the non-english windows users, the ini file will be changed to some other default encodings. Some hidden chars will show up then, however you won't see it from any text editor, but unfortunately Python will read those hidden chars.

I'm not quite sure about Japanese language. When I deal with Simplified/Traditional Chinese Windows/Linux Ubuntu/MacOS ini files encoding, read/write the ini files in "utf-8-sig" works for me, you can give it a shot.

```
with open('config.ini', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The file was saved as 'UTF-8 with BOM' encoding. When it is edited and saved by notepad in windows, it will be automatically saved as like this.